# Function in ng-repeat keeps looping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm loading a list of items using `ng-repeat`. In one of the fields I pass the `ID` I get from the `ng-repeat` to a function to get info from another database table. When I do this and `console.log` the result, it just keeps looping.

```
<ion-slide-box ng-repeat="q in questions.list track by $index">
      <ion-slide class="default box">
        <div class="amount">{{ getAmountQuestion(q.guid) }}</div>
        <div class="question"><h5>{{ q.fields.question }}</h5></div>
      </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>


$scope.getQuestionAmount = function(id) {
    QuestionsService.getAllVotesById(id).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.count);
    });
};
```

Comment: how many elements are in questions.list? can you provide a plnkr ?

Comment: For performance reasons alone, I'd rewrite the `getQuestionAmount()`-function and the backend REST service to take the guids from all questions and return all votes, because in the current setup, it will run a loop and call your REST service for each question.

Comment: @NitsanBaleli 34 at the moment

Comment: @Greg Johannes Jander is right. but any way, do you get more console.logs than items in questions.list ?

Comment: you can't do things like that in the view. Do it in your service. The digest cycles run many times so you are making an insane number of requests and causing more digests to occur making more crazy numbers of requests

Comment: @charlietfl since he is not assigning anything to the scope, I doubt his code triggers more digest cycles. However, you are absolutely right that his code would run a couple of times and go on a AJAX rampage. You should make it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an API service call inside a `watchExpression` is a **really bad idea** because the AngularJS framework calls that expression on **every digest cycle**.

From the Docs:

> The `watchExpression` is called on every call to [$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) and should return the value that will be watched. (`watchExpression` should not change its value when executed multiple times with the same input because it may be executed multiple times by [$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest). That is, `watchExpression` should be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

-- [AngularJS API Reference -- $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Refactor your code to execute the API calls inside the controller, cache the results, and in your watch expression use something like `{{ cachedAmountQuestion[q.guid] }}`.